# WebSocket Disconnect: No route found for path 'ws/chat_app/3wVCio/'

Tags: python, django, websocket

When I try to connect to handshake with my WebSocket, I'm getting the following error in Django terminal:

```
python3.12/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 134, in __call__
    raise ValueError("No route found for path %r." % path)
ValueError: No route found for path 'ws/chat_app/3wVCio/'.
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat_app/3wVCio/ [192.168.0.11:58136]
```

I found, that in previous Django versions, the problem was, that instead of `path`, for defining the `urlpatterns` in this case, it should be used `url()`. However, the `url()` is depricated and instead of it, the re_path should be used. Unfortunately it did not help me..

Here is the routing, I created - `routing.py`

```py
from django.urls import re_path
from .consumers import ChatConsumer

# The WebSocket URL pattern for chat rooms is defined by this code
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'chat_app/(?P<unique_id>\w+)/$', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),

]
```

This is the WebSocket `consumer.py`:

```py
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from .models import Message
from room_app.models import Room

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):

        self.unique_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['unique_id']
        self.room_group_name = f'chat_{self.unique_id}'

        # Check if the room exists in the database
        if not await self.room_exists():
            await self.close()
            return

        # Join room group
        self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Save message to database
        Message.objects.create(
            room=self.unique_id,
            user=self.scope['user'],
            content=message
        )

        # Send message to room group
        self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message,
                'username': self.scope['user'].username
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        username = event['username']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'username': username
        }))
    
    @sync_to_async
    def room_exists(self):
        return Room.objects.filter(unique_id=self.unique_id).exists()
```

The way, that I have configured my project `asgi.py`

```py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                websocket_urlpatterns
            ),
        )
    })
```

I have installed 'daphne' and added it into my `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS`, where I have also defined my `ASGI_APPLICATION` and configured `CHANNEL_LAYERS`:

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'project.asgi.application'

# Configure channel layers
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('192.168.0.11', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

I have also included the `websocket_urlpatterns` in my project `urls.py` like so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...,
    path('ws/', include(websocket_urlpatterns)),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me:

1. I have installed `daphne` `pip install daphne` and added it into my `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py:

```py
    # Application definition
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'daphne',
        ...,
    ]
```

2. I have added `ASGI_APPLICATION` in `settings.py` and configured my `asgi.py`.
   In `settings.py`:

```py
    ASGI_APPLICATION = 'project.asgi.application'
```

3. In `asgi.py`:

```py
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
    
    application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
                URLRouter(
                    websocket_urlpatterns
                ),
            )
        })
```

I'm sorry, that I cannot give explanation why all of these worked. I just wanted to show, what worked for me.

> WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/chat_app/FxmZiA/ [192.168.0.11:60081]

> WebSocket CONNECT /ws/chat_app/FxmZiA/ [192.168.0.11:60081]